How can I discard events that have a null field and take the others that do not have that field?
I have events coming from a Kafka queue, and some of them have the tipoLinea field equal to null or equal to "I" or "E". I need to take only those with the field equal to "I" or "E" and discard the null ones. The problem is that not all events have this field, so if I insert checks at the beginning of the method, it will also discard events without the tipoLinea field. How can I solve this?
public SvuNotifyRequest elabEvent(RiotEvent event) 
    {
        log.debug("call elabEvent({})", event);
        Map<String, RiotItem> riotTypes = svuConfigurationService.getRiotTypes();
        String key              = SvuUtils.toUpperCase(event.getTipo()) + Constants.SEP + SvuUtils.toUpperCase(event.getSottotipo());
        RiotItem riotItem       = riotTypes.get(key);
        SvuNotifyRequest notify = null;

        //new controll
        if (event.getTipoLinea() == null || event.getTipoLinea().isEmpty() ||
                (!"E".equalsIgnoreCase(event.getTipoLinea()) && !"I".equalsIgnoreCase(event.getTipoLinea()))) {
            log.debug("Event discarded because tipoLinea is null, empty or invalid: {}", event);
            return null;
        }
        //end

        if (Assorted.notNull(riotItem) && Assorted.notNull(event.getIdentificativoEvento()))
        {
            Date currentDate                    = new Date();
            Optional<SvuEventDocument> itemOpt  = svuEventRepository.findById(event.getIdentificativoEvento());
            SvuEventDocument item               = null;
            
            if (itemOpt.isPresent())
            {
                item = itemOpt.get();
            } else {
                item = new SvuEventDocument();
                item.setId(event.getIdentificativoEvento());
                item.setCreationDate(Integer.valueOf(Assorted.dateToString(currentDate, Constants.DATE_WITHOUT_TIME_FORMAT)));
                item.setHistory(new ArrayList<>());
            }

            item.setSource(ESources.RIOT.getCode());
            String name = event.getNomElementoDiRete() + Constants.SEP2 + event.getSottotipo();
            item.setScope(riotItem.getScope());
            item.setEvent(name);
            item.setParameter(Assorted.notNull(determineUnavailablePrmtr(riotItem, event)) 
                              ? determineUnavailablePrmtr(riotItem, event)
                              : riotItem.getParameter());
            HistoryItem historyItem     = getLastHistoryItem(item);
            HistoryItem historyItemNew  = new HistoryItem();
            String previousStatus       = null;
            
            item.getHistory().add(historyItemNew);
            historyItemNew.setVersion(1);
            historyItemNew.setIsLastVersion(true);
            if (Assorted.notNull(historyItem))
            {
                historyItem.setIsLastVersion(false);
                historyItemNew.setVersion(historyItem.getVersion() + 1);
                previousStatus = historyItem.getStatus();
            }
            
            historyItemNew.setTimestamp(currentDate.getTime());
            historyItemNew.setIssue(riotItem.getIssue());
            historyItemNew.setRegion(SvuUtils.convertRegionList(SvuUtils.getRegionCodes(Arrays.asList(event.getRegione()))));

            if (Assorted.notNull(event.getDataInizioEvento()))
                historyItemNew.setStartDate(event.getDataInizioEvento() * 1000);
            else
                historyItemNew.setStartDate(currentDate.getTime());

            if (Assorted.notNull(event.getDataFineEvento()))
                historyItemNew.setEndDate(event.getDataFineEvento() * 1000);
            
            historyItemNew.setStatus(SvuUtils.calcoloData(currentDate.getTime(), historyItemNew.getStartDate(), historyItemNew.getEndDate()));
            
            ERiotStatus riotStatus      = ERiotStatus.fromCode(event.getStatoEvento());
            EGlobalStatus globalStatus  = null;
            
            if ((!Assorted.notNull(riotStatus)) || EGlobalStatus.ANNULL.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(riotStatus.getCode()))
            {    
                globalStatus = EGlobalStatus.ANNULL;
                log.warn("For event {} the status {} is unknown or canceled {}", event.getIdentificativoEvento(), event.getStatoEvento(), event.getNotify());
            } else if(Constants.TERMINATED_STATUS.equalsIgnoreCase(historyItemNew.getStatus())){
                globalStatus = EGlobalStatus.CLOSED;
            }
            else {
                globalStatus = EGlobalStatus.OPEN;
            }
            
            item.setGlobalStatus(globalStatus.getCode());  
            svuEventRepository.save(item);
            
            
            SvuNotifyItem notiItem = new SvuNotifyItem( toast(historyItemNew.getIssue(), historyItemNew.getStatus(), previousStatus,
                                                              historyItemNew.getStartDate(), historyItemNew.getEndDate(), currentDate.getTime()),
                                                        item.getScope(),
                                                        item.getParameter(), 
                                                        item.getEvent(),  
                                                        historyItemNew.getStatus(), 
                                                        historyItemNew.getIssue());
            notify = new SvuNotifyRequest();
            notify.setNotify(event.getNotify());
            notify.setDate(currentDate.getTime());
            addNotify(notify, notiItem, historyItemNew.getStartDate(), historyItemNew.getEndDate());
            
        } else {
            
            if (!Assorted.notNull(riotItem))
                log.error("NO CONFIGURATION for event: Type: {}, SubType: {}, Key: {}. Check collection svu_configuration", event.getTipo(), event.getSottotipo(), event.getIdentificativoEvento());
            else if (!Assorted.notNull(event.getIdentificativoEvento()))
                log.error("The field \"identificativoEvento\" is null {}.", event);
        }
        
        return notify;
    }

